# Spring Boot 3 Security requestMatchers.permitAll not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

Below is the `SecurityFilterChain` bean created according to the new Spring Security 6 / Spring boot 3 documentation. However, `requestMatchers -> AntPathRequestMatcher -> permitAll` is not working. Every request is reaching `OncePerRequestFilter`. Please let me know if this is expected or if something is wrong.

Code:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {
   List<String> publicApis = List.of("/generate/**", "validated/**");
   
   @Bean
   public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .cors()
                .configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource())
                .and()
                .csrf()
                .disable()
                .formLogin()
                .disable()
                .httpBasic()
                .disable()
                .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(restAuthenticationEntryPoint())
                .and()
                .authorizeHttpRequests(
                        r -> r.requestMatchers(
                                        publicApis().stream()
                                                .map(AntPathRequestMatcher::new)
                                                .toArray(RequestMatcher[]::new)
                                )
                                .permitAll()
                                .anyRequest()
                                .authenticated()
                )
                .sessionManagement(s -> s.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .addFilterBefore(tokenAuthenticationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public WebSecurityCustomizer webSecurityCustomizer() {
        return (web) -> web.ignoring().requestMatchers(publicApis.toArray(String[]::new));
    }
}
```

SecurityFilter class:

```
@Component
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

@Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(@NonNull HttpServletRequest request, @NonNull HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
 log.info("request:{}", request); // all requests are logging including `/generate/a` or `/validate/1`
}

}
```

Ideally `/generate/a` or `/validate/1` should not go to SecurityFilter. Still, there are going for JWT validation. How to avoid public APIs to bypass SecurityFilter.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `SecurityFilter` is a `@Component`, therefore the filter will be picked up by Spring Boot and added to the filter chain.

Note that the filter chain that I mentioned is not the same chain as Spring Security, which is the `SecurityFilterChain`. Spring Security will not invoke the `SecurityFilterChain` for the endpoints you mentioned, because you did:

```java
@Bean
public WebSecurityCustomizer webSecurityCustomizer() {
    return (web) -> web.ignoring().requestMatchers(publicApis.toArray(String[]::new));
}
```

I believe that since you are ignoring those endpoints, you do not need to `permitAll` them (those are different things).

One way to solve this is by adding the `SecurityFilter` to the `SecurityFilterChain` (which is not invoked for those endpoints):

1. Remove `@Component` from your `SecurityFilter`
2. Do `http.addFilter(Before/After/At)(new SecurityFilter(), BeforeFilter.class)`

Comment: I removed @Component and added .addFilterBefore(new SecurityFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
There is no `BeforeFilter.class` as such. 
Still I can see permitAll requests reaching SecurityFilter.doFilterInternal()

Comment: Also no luck removing `authorizeHttpRequests` at `SecurityFilterChain`

Comment: The `BeforeFilter` is a placeholder, you'd have to choose which filter you want to put it before. You can try `http.addFilterAfter(new SecurityFilter(), AuthorizationFilter.class)` this way it will only be invoked for authorized requests.

Comment: My security config class (AppWebSecurityConfig) have the code as suggested here. Out of 5 ignore URIs list ["/login","/h2-console/**", "/actuator/refresh", "/swagger-ui/**", "/v3/api-docs/**"], I am getting unauthorize for "/h2-console/**", "/actuator/refresh".  Running out of clue on solving this. Any pointers will be appreciated.

Comment: Panda, please refer to this answer https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/12310#issuecomment-1328990026 or open a new question if it doesn’t work for you

Answer (score 1):

You can create a SecurityFilterChain `@Bean` and pass a list of endpoinds that needs to be pass

```
private static final String[] AUTH_WHITELIST = {
        "/swagger-resources",
        "/swagger-resources/**",
        "/configuration/ui",
        "/configuration/security",
        "/swagger-ui.html",
        "/webjars/**",
        "/v3/api-docs/**",
        "/api/public/**",
        "/api/public/authenticate",
        "/actuator/*",
        "/swagger-ui/**"
};
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize
                    .requestMatchers(AUTH_WHITELIST).permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
            )
            .httpBasic(withDefaults());
    return http.build();
}
```