# Spring security RequestMatcher is not working and always it invoked SecurityFilterChain

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am using the latest spring-boot-starter-security 3.1.1. I am trying to use spring security in my application where the frontend sends a token in a cookie. I have written a CookieAuthenticationFilter which fetches this token and performs the authentication. If the authentication is successful then it loads "userInfo". This is working fine. But I want to permit specific endpoints which don't require this authentication like actuator & some custom endpoints.

I configured it in @EnableWenSecurity configuration class but it never works, It always calls CookieAuthenticationFilter,

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity(debug = true)
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class AppAuthenticationInterceptor {
    private final UserAuthenticationEntryPoint userAuthenticationEntryPoint;
    private final UserAuthenticationProvider userAuthenticationProvider;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.exceptionHandling(
                        customizer -> customizer.authenticationEntryPoint(userAuthenticationEntryPoint))
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .addFilterBefore(
                        new CookieAuthenticationFilter(userAuthenticationProvider),
                        BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
                //              .addFilterBefore(new JwtAuthFilter(userAuthenticationProvider),
                // CookieAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .sessionManagement(
                        session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS));

        http.authorizeHttpRequests(
                requests ->
                        requests.requestMatchers("/actuator/**").permitAll() // Specify the endpoints that should be excluded from token
                                // validation
                                .requestMatchers("/api/v2/config").permitAll()
                                .requestMatchers("api/v2/config").permitAll()
                                .requestMatchers("/error").permitAll()
                                .anyRequest()
                                .authenticated());

        return http.build();
    }
}
```

And this is my CookieAuthenticationFilter,

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CookieAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

  private final UserAuthenticationProvider userAuthenticationProvider;

  @Override
  protected void doFilterInternal(
      HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
      throws ServletException, IOException {
    try {
      // Check if "openIdAccessToken" cookie exists
      String accessToken =
          Arrays.stream(request.getCookies())
              .filter(cookie -> cookie.getName().equals("openidAccessToken"))
              .findFirst()
              .map(Cookie::getValue)
              .orElse(null);

      if (isBlank(accessToken)) {
        String authHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        if (isBlank(authHeader) && authHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
          accessToken = authHeader.substring(7);
        }
      }
      String opco = request.getParameter("opco");
      SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
          .setAuthentication(userAuthenticationProvider.validateCredentials(accessToken, opco));
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
      SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
      throw e;
    }
    filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
  }
}
```

But the endpoint Which I want to permit are not working. CookieAuthenticationFilter still intercepts the "api/v2/config" endpoints. How to fix this? Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: please enable spring security trace logs and edit your question to include them so we can actually see what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

I followed this correct answer [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74799091/spring-boot-3-security-requestmatchers-permitall-not-working)
by using 'ignoring()', it works for me.